# Is there a clean way to disable a C++ feature macro?

Tags: c++, c++17

We have a module that pulls in 3rd-party, specifically `sqlite_modern_cpp` although I don't think that is particularly important. What is important is that code uses C++ feature macros and (specifically) tests for `__cpp_lib_uncaught_exceptions` to know whether `std::uncaught_exceptions` is defined.

So far so good, except that we are now looking to change our C++ standard from C++14 to C++17. On iOS builds (don't know fully about other targets) this is suddenly defined. However, we target a minimum version of iOS as 9.3 and, with that, the compiler returns an error to say the minimum value of iOS required is 10.0.

I would prefer, if possible, not to touch the third party code, so my ideal solution to this would be to tell the compiler not to defined `__cpp_lib_uncaught_exceptions`, so it would fall back to the previous solution. Is there a clean way to do that?

Comment: Which compiler are you using for your iOS builds?

Comment: Macros are evaluated at compile time. I cannot imagine how to change a library (which was already compiled) to consider differently set macros.

Comment: This specific library is being pulled in as source, but typically we build libraries from source so the issue would be similar.

We are using a slightly old version of Xcode, which in turn using clang IIRC. (Xcode is called via cmake)

Comment: It seems strange that sqlite would be using a std feature test macro to determine a different minimum supported OS version. Is there any discussion in it's changelog?

Comment: To me the issue is with clang. It is saying that the feature is supported but then saying it is not - it is supported by the language but is effectively not because the minimum version of iOS is not high enough.

Comment: Note that xcode clang isn't "real clang", it is a proprietary fork of clang by apple.  And your problem appears to be in that fork code.  (ie, don't assign the blame to clang)

Comment: I was not thinking this was a "real clang" or whatever issue. I was thinking there might be a more official way of changing the behaviour via a flag, to avoid changing the code. Seems note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature test macros are just normal macros, which you can `#undef`. Include `<exception>` first to define the macro, then undef, then include the library. `sqlite_modern_cpp` is a header only library, so this should cause no problems.

```
#include <exception>
#undef __cpp_lib_uncaught_exceptions
#include "sqlite_modern_cpp.h"
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this, although guarded so only on iOS if the min recommended target was less that v10.0. Seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

This is intended to be handled by the [availability mechanic](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/43ff058e78d9e4fa47080b61fc3811da80db1b3f/libcxx/include/__availability#L19) in libcxx. For example, `__cpp_lib_shared_mutex` is [controlled](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/e4dee762245d1fefc6bcae643ecc55063aef2e9c/libcxx/include/version#L251) by the preprocessor symbol `_LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_DISABLE_FTM___cpp_lib_shared_mutex`, which is [defined](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/43ff058e78d9e4fa47080b61fc3811da80db1b3f/libcxx/include/__availability#L155) according to the minimum declared target versions of the various Apple OSes.

It should be fairly easy to copy this mechanic to similarly define a `_LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_DISABLE_FTM___cpp_lib_uncaught_exceptions` to disable `__cpp_lib_uncaught_exceptions`; you would need to patch the headers `<version>` and `<__availability>`. You might want to update the Clang [issue 39631](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39631), which was closed back in 2018 (I believe incorrectly, but maybe the availability mechanic didn't exist back then).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried just defining some similar in the cmake toolchain I have. It seemed to do little more than changing the error message.